# Conversion Hive datediff() to months

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, datediff

When using **Hive** there is the functionality to return the `select datediff('date1','date2') from table` value which returns the number of days between two dates.
What if I would be interested in the months between the two dates?

One option would be to divide the result by 30.5, as the average months has approximately 30.5 days, but this would certainly yield an inprecision when large date ranges are considered.

Do you know a way of retrieving the **number of months** (rather than the number of days) in a similar fashion with standard SQL (ideally HIVE) syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTHS_BETWEEN(date1, date2) AS INT) as numberOfMonthsBetweenDates
FROM table
```

This will return your expected result.

Comment: That is smart :)

Comment: what about minutes and hours between?